# Python - How to solve OS Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, subprocess, command-line-interface

I'm running this command:

```
AWS_PROFILE=sandbox aws s3 cp local_path bucket --recursive
```

and this works just fine. I want to run a python script. This is my code:

```
cmd = ['AWS_PROFILE=sandbox', 'aws', 's3', 'cp', local_path, bucket, '--recursive']
subprocess.Popen(cmd).communicate()
```

and it doesn't work.

Error traceback:

```
File "bin/run_report.py", line 128, in main
    subprocess.Popen(cmd).communicate()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1025, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I have triple checked the path to local and to bucket, as mentioned, it works from the shell (I don't want to run shell=True)

Comment: Are you sure local path and bucket are correct?

Comment: You want to use `--profile sandbox` instead

Comment: ``subprocess.Popen(cmd).communicate()`` was trying to run ``AWS_PROFILE=sandbox`` as the command.  There is of course no command called that so the errno 2 is thrown, which means "No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `aws` cli `--profile` switch to choose the profile.

```py
cmd = ['aws', '--profile=sandbox', 's3', 'cp', '--recursive', local_path, bucket]
print(' '.join(cmd))
subprocess.Popen(cmd).communicate()
```

The command should now read:

```
aws --profile=sandbox s3 cp --recursive local_path bucket
```